# Inequality $\sqrt{2x+3} < 1-\sqrt{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Whole inequality is defined only on $x > -\frac{3}{2}$, left part only positive, and with right part being negative inequality won't work. This leave with $x \in (-\frac{3}{2};-1)$.
Answer to inequality will be in $\sqrt{2x+3} < 1-\sqrt{x+2}$. Solving it as equation and using interval method gives me the answer $(2-2\sqrt{3}; - 1)$. But the actual answer is $(-\frac{3}{2};2-2\sqrt{3})$. What am I missing?
Can't upload picture, I'll leave the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3sL1.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your solution is that you squared $x< -2\sqrt{x+2}$ to obtain $x^2 < 4(x+2)$.  Both sides of that inequality are negative.  When you square it, you must flip $<$ to $>$

The straightforward way to solve this problem is to move square roots to one side:
$$\sqrt{2x+3} + \sqrt{x+2} < 1$$

Since LHS is now monotonously increasing and you already determined that the corresponding equation has a root at $2-2\sqrt3$, the answer to the inequality is $(-\infty, 2-2\sqrt3)$  intersected with the LHS's domain $(-\frac{3}{2}, \infty)$

Answer (score 2):

Mistake lies in the step:
$$ x < -2\sqrt{x+2}$$
doesn't imply, $x^2< 4(x+2)$. Because the above inequality implies that $x$ is negative. When two quantities $a$ and $b $ are negative such that $a<b$, it is not true that $a^2<b^2$. Instead $b^2<a^2$ is true. Hence you should have taken, $$ 4(x+2) < x^2$$